# Javascript - Prevent form submit if min and max condition is not fulfilled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript to display an error when user click on form submit button if the number entered is not in between min and max. The issue is when you click submit button the form will submit regardless. Can you please look at the code below and tell me what I need to add. I need to prevent form from submitting if the min and max condition is not fulfilled.

html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="validation.js"></script></head>
<body>


<form name="form1" >
          <label>Enter Amount</label>
          <input id="amount" type="number"  value="0" min="5" max="10" step="1"/>
          <p id="error"></p>
          <br/>
          <label>Charity you wish to donate to</label>
          <input type="text" name="charity"></input>
          <br/>
          <button id="save_choice"  onclick="amountFunction()">Save Choice</button>
          <button><a href="#" target="_blank">Save Choice</a></button> 
            </form>

<p id="error"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
     var inpObj = document.getElementById("amount");
if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
    return false
} else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Input OK";
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: try `<button id="save_choice"  onclick="return amountFunction()">Save Choice</button>` and you try to show error after return... so, error would not show.

Comment: Apologies i posted wrong js. please have look at the above updated js

Comment: Note: beware of the accepted answer on the question that this question was marked a duplicate of. I commented there as to why.

Comment: I noticed that your original JavaScript and now the updated code are both missing semicolons after your return statements. This could cause issues for you in the future.

Comment: Thanks guys. Its working

Answer (score -1):

Taking advantage of the fact that you already have jQuery in the page, you can do it with the event listeners.

```
$("form[name=form1]").on("submit", amountFunction);

function amountFunction(ev){
     var inpObj = document.getElementById("amount");
     if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
         ev.preventDefault();
         $("#error").text("Value should be between " + $(inpObj).attr("min") + " and " + $(inpObj).attr("max"));
         return false;
     } else {
         document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Input OK";
         return true;
     } 
}
```

Note: the event listener declaration should run when the page finished loading.

Comment: Thank you soo much. that worked

Comment: I'm glad it worked. ;)

Comment: I would like to output a error message like "Amount must be in between 1 and 10" but the two numbers min and max should not be hard coded instead value must come from within the min and max attribute inside html. It should be something like   innerHTML = Amount must be between $(min) and $(max). Can you please advice. thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the message, that should work. If it doesn't try changing $(inpObj).attr("min") for $(inpObj).prop("min") i can't remember if those are attributes or properties.

Comment: Yes!! that worked. thanks once again